# SOQL Injection Prevention

Tags: apex, soql, soql-injection

In the below scenario  i am Accepting the ID of object in the string form :
What will be the best way to avoid the SQL injection for ASId.

```
public static List<AB__c>ABC(string ASId)

       records = [select id, name,abc__c,der__f, from AB__c WHERE der__f = :ASId WITH SECURITY ENFORCED ORDER BY AB__c ASC NULLS LAST];
```

Comment: The best way to avoid it is to use static soql which is currently used in your sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no "injection" going on here. If the user can't see the record, they'll get no results back. You can improve this code a bit by using `Id` instead of `String`, but that will only change the error they'll get since the method will fail to run with an invalid Id. Injection is really only possible with poorly built methods that accept a SOQL string and don't validate it sufficiently. It's generally inadvisable to create methods that directly run a SOQL string provided by a user.

Comment: but with this code i am getting checkmarx error is there any way to avoid it.