# SOQL Injection error in the Checkmarx scanner report

Tags: soql, checkmarx, soql-injection

I am facing below error:

In the below Scenario, I have tested it properly but still in order to avoid the SOQL injection, But when I am running the Checkmarx I am getting error as below:

```java
public static List<AB__c>getAccountInfo(String ASId){

       records = [
                     SELECT id, name, defer__c,
                     FROM AB__c 
                     WHERE der__f = :ASId 
                     WITH SECURITY ENFORCED 
                     ORDER BY AB__c ASC 
                     NULLS LAST
       ];
}
```

checkmarx Error :

> Method getAccountInfo gets user input from element ASId. This input is
>   later concatenated by application directly into a string variable
>   contating SQL commands, without being validated,The string is used in
>   the method to query the database without any additional filtering by
>   database . This could allow the User to tamper with tha parameter.

Is there any way I can correct this code on behalf of checkmarx report?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of [SOQL Injection Prevention](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/296147/soql-injection-prevention)

Comment: I am not able to clear out the checkmarx with this code

Comment: Is there any way i can pass this checkmarx on the basis of my code as this code is not good in the way to prevent the SOQl injection

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions under multiple accounts. Please do use the Contact link at the bottom of every page to have Stack Exchange merge your accounts.